# Setting up the RPi in a VM beforehand

Tags: software-installation, setup

I want to set up my raspberry pi as a multi-purpose server. My problem is that I have no access to a screen or a keyboard for it. Thus I wanted to set up everything in a VM (booted from the SD card) and then simply put the SD card into the RPi, and boot from it. Is it therefore possible to tell the VM (f.ex. qemu) to boot from the SD card, while retaining it bootable for the RPi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up using an image file, and then dd the image file onto the SD card when done. I have used something like this:

```
qemu-system-arm.exe -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -hda 2016-02-09-raspbian-jessie.img -kernel kernel-qemu -m 256 -nographic -append "root=/dev/sda2" -redir tcp:2222::22
```

2016-02-09-raspbian-jessie.img is the bootable image.

When it's prepared you can install with the the usual:

```
dd bs=4M if=2016-02-09-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/sdd
```

If you use a bootable image, you can even do the prep work on windows if you would like to.

You can get the kernel from here: https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel

The Kernel for qemu is never copied into the image - so doesn't affect the boot on a real pi.

You ssh to this image when running by connecting to port 2222 on localhost

Comment: I will try that, and accept on success afterwards. Thanks!